# who open shared files on Windows 7 powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, share

I need determine who open file on my computer from lan,and I want automate it.

I tried use:

*net files* show me opened file but I see user GUEST, but I need computer name on my lan to send message to it.

*net session* give me computer but I can see which files open.
powershell v 2.0

I found this script but it show me only user like GUEST

```
function get-openfiles{
    param(
    $computername=@($env:computername),
    $verbose=$false)
    $collection = @()
    foreach ($computer in $computername){
        $netfile = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/LanmanServer"
        $netfile.Invoke("Resources") | foreach {
        try{
        $collection += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
        Id = $.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        itemPath = $.GetType().InvokeMember("Path", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        UserName = $.GetType().InvokeMember("User", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        LockCount = $.GetType().InvokeMember("LockCount", 'GetProperty', $null, $, $null)
        Server = $computer
        }
    }
        catch{
        if ($verbose){write-warning $error[0]}
        }
        }
}
Return $collection
}
```

**UPDATE**

So this script get me output on my mashine
[image: script output]
We can see here user GUEST.
Open Control Managments->Sharefolder->Session and see 3 user open file
[image: Session]
Here we see Anna PC open 3 file and Art-PC open 9 file.
Open Control Managments->Sharefolder->openfiles
[image: opened files]
But how i can uderstand who open which file?

Comment: Your script was purposed to return all currently opened files on a system, not to provide auditing capability for files that have been opened previously on your machine. I've tested it and it works fine. What exactly is the question? Is there a scripting issue?

Comment: I update post to show images